# AJAX success function works, but file isn't running

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to StackOverflow, web development, and I'm low on time for this assignment, so I apologize if I'm a bit slower at understanding web development vocabulary and any answers or tips. I'm having trouble with calling another php file through ajax.
index.php:

```
<!--------------------------- HTML STARTUP ----------------------------------->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>        
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="finalproject.css" />

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="finalproject.js"></script>

        <title>Final Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<!--------------------------- LOGIN ------------------------------------------>

<?php
    require_once 'dbconnection.php';

//----------------------- CREATE USERS TABLE -----------------------------------

$userspass = "CREATE TABLE usersPass (
    userID VARCHAR(60),
    password VARCHAR(60)
);";

$connected->query($userspass);

$selectAllInfo = "SELECT * FROM usersPass;";
$connected->query($selectAllInfo);

//-------------------------- LOG IN OR REGISTER --------------------------------
?>
    <form id="trial"><button onclick="OpenRegister()">Sign Up!</button>
    <script>
$(document).on("click" , "#Register", function(e)
    {
       var datastring = $("#trial").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'userlogin.php',
            data: datastring,
            success: function(data){
            alert('Sign Up function is a success!');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
        </script></form>
    <br/><br/>
    <button onclick="InputInfo()">Login</button> 

<?php        
$connected->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the JavaScript when the function is called.
finalproject.js:

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/

function OpenRegister() {
'use strict';

$('form').append("<div id=SignInContainer>
<span style='font-size: 20px'>UserID</span>
<input type='text' name='UserID' value='Type userID here...'>
<span style='font-size: 20px'>Password</span>
<input type='text' name='UserID' value='Type password here...'>
<button id='Register'>Submit</button>
</div>");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';

    $(document).on('focus', 'input', function () {
        $('input').focus(function () {
            $(this).val('');
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the php file I'm trying to load. userlogin.php:

```
<?php echo "If this displays, you win." ?>
```

dbconnection.php

```
<?php
$connected = new mysqli('localhost', 'Username', 'Password', 'Username');
mysqli_select_db($connected, 'cferna50');

// Check connection
if ($connected->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connected->connect_error);
}
```

I'm just trying to get the "userlogin.php"file to run through AJAX. I'm running this thing on Chrome. I've heard that there is a bit of a problem with using AJAX on local files, but I tried that --access-file-from-files thing and it didn't help. I tried running it on FireFox and Internet Explorer and it still doesn't help. I'm sure I have everything in the same directory. I'm using an online school server thing to do all this. I've been hurting my head over this for endless hours, any help would GREATLY be appreciated.

Comment: Have you included all your code here? Your ajax function doesn't seem to be passing any form data. Have you left it out of your example? If you have put it back in as it is confusing. If this is all of your code, you need to pass your form data. You are not posting any data at present.

Comment: Flag at chromium, chrome should be `--allow-file-access-from-files` . The `html` string at `.append()` does not appear to be concatenated correctly to avoid syntax error. What is expected result of `if($("#Register").click())`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply because you are not passing (data) through the method, either you [Serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the data or pass them individually, and i suppose you will use the first method to save time

```
<script>
    $(document).on("submit","#loginForm", function(e)
        {
           var datastring = $("#loginForm").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'userlogin.php',
                data: datastring,
                success: function(data){
                 alert(data);
                //or
                //alert('Sign Up function is a success!');
            },
                error: function(){
                 alert("error handling");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form id="loginForm" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" placeholder="user ID" />
  <input type="text" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['userid'])){
   $username = $_POST['userid'];
   $pass = $_POST['password'];

   //do your magic now
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: It's going through with the success function, but it still doesn't run the php file for some reason.

Comment: Wrap the inputs with <form> & code paste the code i gave you, remember to add (id) to the form and change the value $("#formID").serialize(); according to the form (id)

Comment: I think I did as you said:

    <form id="trial"><button onclick="OpenRegister()">Sign Up!</button>
        <script>
    $(document).on("click" , "#Register", function(e)
        {
           var datastring = $("trial").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'userlogin.php',
                data: datastring,
                success: function(data){
                alert('Sign Up function is a success!');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
            </script></form>

The result had the input appear for

Comment: a very short second :P

Comment: Put the inputs inside the form and don't forget to add hash here `$("trial").serialize();` should be `$("#trial").serialize();`

Comment: Nothing seems to have changed, unfortunately :(

Comment: Mam you are doing something wrong for sure,  post the whole code after making changes

Comment: Please put all inputs inside a form tag with id=loginForm, change the value here to `$("#loginForm").serialize();`  & move the ajax script outside the form, above it , it's so easy why you are making it hard  .. focus

Comment: I did that, but it still isn't working D: I'm still only getting the "success" function, but not the userlogin.php file to run.

Comment: It's only alerting the 'data' from "success", but it still doesn't run the userlogin.php file :/ It seems to be locating it, but it just won't run it, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Correct concatenation of `html` string at `.append()` remove `if($("#Register").click())`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function SignUp() {
  if ($("[name=username]").val().length 
     && $("[name=password]").val().length) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'userlogin.php',
      data: {
          username: $("[name=username]").val(),
          password: $("[name=password]").val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert('Sign Up function is a success!');
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("stacsnippets success")
      }
    });
    }
  }
</script>
<script>
  function OpenRegister() {
    'use strict';

    $('body').append("<div id=SignInContainer>" 
      + "<span style='font-size: 20px'>UserID</span>" 
      + "<input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Type userID here...'>" 
      + "<span style='font-size: 20px'>Password</span>" 
      + "<input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Type password here...'>" 
      + "<button onclick='SignUp()' id='Register'>Submit</button>" 
      + "</div>");
  }
</script>
<button onclick="OpenRegister()">Sign Up!</button>
```

php

```
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
  // do username, password validation stuff here
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qnrnn5b5/

Comment: It's running the success message, but it still isn't running the userlogin.php file :(

Comment: Are you trying to `POST` data to `userlogin.php`?

Comment: I've had trouble understanding the difference between "Post" and "Get", so I'll just explain what I'm trying to do in userlogin.php. I just want to verify the username and password that the user inputs into the "inputs" in the OpenRegister function.

Comment: That is possible, though not with `php` at Question. The request is sent, though you need to send the values of `<input>` elements, also elements should probably have different `name` attribute values

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for other solutions in the meantime. But what you said  makes sense... So I'm guessing I need to find some other method.